# Go To File with directory in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

The "Go to File" dialog is handy (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd>), but my project has a hundred files called `index.phtml`. Is there any way to include the directory? Say, search for `docs/index.phtml`?

Or do I just have to fix/wait for https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222697?

I'm using NetBeans PHP 7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only file names can be searched for.

When looking at the code of the `Jump To` module, you can notice that a `org.netbeans.modules.parsing.spi.indexing.CustomIndexerFactory` gets registered which only keeps record of file names including their extension. So currently there is no way to to search for files with a path specified.

However, I think it shouldn't be too difficult to change the indexer of the `Jump To` module to not omit the path, I'd worry about the performance though.